# Android: simple replace fragment with an other fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I've run into an issue with my code.

**What I want**

My Activity starts automatically with Fragment01. 
On Fragment01, there is a button, which should replace Fragment01 with Fragment02

**What happens**

When I press the button, instead of replacing Fragment01, I can still see Fragment01 in the background

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.lucky.fragmentexample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button bn;
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        bn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

        bn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            Fragment02 fragment02 = new Fragment02();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.button_fragment_container, fragment02);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/button_fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment01"
            android:name="com.lucky.fragmentexample.Fragment01"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `fragment` element in your layout XML can only ever refer to that single fragment and can't be swapped out in the way you intend. Instead, you need to remove the `fragment` element from your layout XML entirely and add your `Fragment01` into your container `FrameLayout` in code in the `onCreate()` method of your activity.

So, remove the `fragment` element, like so;

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
    <FrameLayout
       android:id="@+id/button_fragment_container"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent" 
       />
</LinearLayout>
```

Then you can perform your transaction in the beginning of your `onCreate()` override, like so;

```
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.button_fragment_container, new Fragment01());
    transaction.commit();
```

You will want to instantiate a new `FragmentTransaction` for each new transaction, which means you'll probably want to remove the `FragmentManager` and `FragmentTransaction` from your instance members and declare them fresh each time you need to make a fragment transaction.

I hope this helps.

Further reading:

- [Official Fragments API Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Adding)

Comment: Hi Rudi, thank you. I edited my code by your recommendation. The Frgment01 on Start works fine. But the App is crashing when I press the Button (show_Fragment02)..

Comment: @Wuuzzaa - It might be because your trying to use the same `FragmentTransaction` to do both replace transactions. Try declaring new ones each time you do replace and commit and take the instance member variables out. If that doesn't work I can't see anything else wrong, and you might need to posts up your logCat stack trace.

Comment: I just had the chance to check it and it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Put beginTransaction inside onclick function and replace R.id.button_fragment_container for R.id.frame_container.

Use this inside onclick:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, new Fragment02()).commit();
```

Fragment inside xml file is not correct. Erase that part.

Answer (score 1):

try this code :

```
     FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
     FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
     fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment01, new Fragment02());
     fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

also, change the 'fragment' to 'FrameLayout' in your xml. This prevents from any one fragment always remaining in the background.

Answer (score 1):

Just go step by step:

First modify your layout, remove the fragment over there and make the reference of your FrameLayout in the activity.

Now initiate your fragment class which you want to add to the framelayout and call following code:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
transaction.remove(removePreviousFragmentIfAny);
transaction.add(R.id.button_fragment_container, newFragment);
transaction.commit();
```

Hope it will help you to go through.